# Make image hide itself if no image was found in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, image, gridview, webforms

The project I'm working on is in ASP.NET web form. So I have a gridview : `<asp:GridView ...>` .

The second columne of this gridview is an image. Since our image bank contains images of different sizes, I had no choice to ajuste the width of the image to a fix number like `<img style="width:160px" ...>`.

It's all good except when the image is not found (which happens a lot), now you have a big empty 160 pixels square with an alternate text inside, and it's pointless.

How can I make it so the image just hide itself if it's not found ?

**ASPX minimal code :**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvMandat" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="ID_ARTICLE_ECOLE" Visible="true" ItemStyle-ForeColor="Transparent" />  
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="<%# (Container.DataItem as MandatMobile.DAL.MandatsEcoleCCadmin_dates_Result).url %>" target="_blank">
                        <img  style="width:160px" alt="-"  src='<%# getImage(Container.DataItem as MandatMobile.DAL.MandatsEcoleCCadmin_dates_Result) %>' ></img>
                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Back end code** (in case you need to see it)

```
protected string getImage(MandatsEcoleCCadmin_dates_Result p)
    {
        using (MandatsDatas db = new MandatsDatas())
        {
            GROUPE_ARTICLE g = db.GROUPE_ARTICLE.First(t => t.ID_GROUPE == p.ID_GROUPE);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(g.Notes))
                return null;

            return "https://webPath.domaine.qc.ca/imageBank/" + g.Notes + ".jpg";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I think a good approach would be to move that code to the on data row bound event.

That will enable you to replace that with a blank image,  a default image, or in fact hide the image control 100%.

so, say this:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Width="150px"
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now above was a simple row with a path name.

But, we could say have this (remove the image url).

Then in row data bound, then this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image MyImage = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image2");
        // get FULL data row information - includes rows NOT display in gv
        // (this is not the gv row!
        DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;


        if (gData["ImagePath"] == null)
            MyImage.Visible = false;
        else
            MyImage.ImageUrl = gData["ImagePath"].ToString();

    }
}
```

of course, in your case, you have a hyper link "a", but you can do the same with that.

eg:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="MyImage" runat="server"></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And then:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlAnchor MyImage = (HtmlAnchor)e.Row.FindControl("MyImage");
        // get FULL data row information - includes rows NOT display in gv
        // (this is not the gv row!
        DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;


            if (gData["ImagePath"] == null)
                MyImage.Visible = false;
            else
                MyImage.HRef = "whatever ";
        }
    }
```

## Edit: full example code

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="45%"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="MyLink" runat="server">
                    <img id="MyImage" runat="server" width="128" />
                </a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code to load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from Fighters ", conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And we get/see this:

[image]

And, the on row data bound event code is this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlAnchor MyLink = (HtmlAnchor)e.Row.FindControl("MyLink");
            HtmlImage MyImage = (HtmlImage)e.Row.FindControl("MyImage");

        // get FULL data row information - includes rows NOT display in gv
        // (this is not the gv row!
        DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (gData["ImagePath"] == null)
                MyImage.Visible = false;
            else
            {
                MyImage.Src = gData["ImagePath"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, my above code does not set, or do anything in regards to the hyper link "a" tag, but the code is free to do so.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great but how does the gridview header looks like ? I'm trying things like `OnDataBound="grvMandat_RowDataBound"` but no succes

Comment: It sais "parameters does not match signature" when I hover my mouse on the name of the function in the aspx file

Comment: Haa ! It was `onRowDataBound="grvMandat_RowDataBound"`

Comment: Yes, I perhaps should have posted more markup - but it is onRowDataBound.

Comment: See my edit - I post the full markup and working code.